# 2D convolution by breaking up mask

Tags: c++, convolution

Is there a way to perform convolution of two matrices (image and mask) by breaking up the mask into 2 smaller chunks and combining the result of the 2 convolutions to get the original single mask convolution result?

Comment: Perhaps this would be better for Math.stackexchange?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, due to linearity of convolution, you can break things up as:

I * M = I * (M1 + M2) = I * M1 + I * M2

where M is your original mask and M1 and M2 are the two smaller chunks.

For example, M could be

```
M = [ 1 1 2 
      2 1 3
      2 1 8 ]
```

and

```
M1 = [ 0 0 0
       0 1 3
       0 1 8 ]

M2 = [ 1 1 2 
       2 0 0 
       2 0 0 ]
```

Just be careful that if you do this, and you want to represent M1 as the smaller,

```
M1 = [ 1 3 
       1 8 ]
```

that you'll have to align them properly before you add them back together.

Comment: Property of distributivity also holds for convolution of sequences in z-domain. The shifted sequence *is* actually M1*z(-1) if the concept is extended to 2D. Just like 31 = 3 **0** + 1, where the zero in 30 must implicitly follow all operations...